# How to redirect user to login page if not logged in and redirect them back to referrer url in magento 2?

Tags: redirect, magento2

I have a page

> mystore.com/interest

which requires user to be logged in. When this controller is hit I redirect customer to

> mystore.com/customer/account/login/

After they login I want them back to

> mystore.com/interest

not to the user dashboard. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Following two possible ways.

```
System > Config > Customer 
> Costumer Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in > NO
```

OR set the following code in after login method.

```
$this->_redirectReferer();
```